# ElasticSearch AnalyzeRequest object for Email search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Using Highlevel client to search emailId from elasticsearch getting empty result. To overcome this issue i am using AnalyseRequest below piece of code i have written

```
AnalyzeRequest request = AnalyzeRequest.buildCustomAnalyzer("logs","uax_url_email")
                    .addCharFilter("html_strip")    
                    .addTokenFilter("lowercase")        
                    .build("gya.nay@gmail.com");
```

seems like above code is not working.

don't understand how to apply customized filter. Anyone tell me how to create AnalyzeRequest object.

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you on ? Have you tried using [Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search.html) ?

Comment: @PhilippeB. i am using ES 7.4.1.Using 
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
 .should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("email", filter.toLowerCase()))
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder().query(boolQuery)
.from((batchNumber - 1) * batchSize).size(batchSize)
    .sort(FieldSortBuilder.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.DESC);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP didn't provide the code of search and might be confused about what is Analyze API and looks like ended up using it for the search operation. Considering all this **I am writing a general answer on how to search for mail-id using Elasticsearch high-level client.**

First, you need to create custom analyzer using [uax_url_email](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html) tokenizer and in ES mapping associate `email` field with this custom analyzer like below:

### ES mapping and settings example of email field using custom analyzer

API Endpoint for creating index :-

`http://{{hostname}}:9200/<index-name>` http Method PUT

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "lowercaseFilter": {
            "type": "lowercase"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "email": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercaseFilter"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "emailId":
      {
        "analyzer": "email",
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once the index is created, index few docs using index API and then use below java high-level rest client to search the mail-id:

### Code

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index-name");
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        if (email != null) {
            MatchQueryBuilder emailMatchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("emailId", email);
            boolQueryBuilder.must(emailMatchQueryBuilder);
        }
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);
        log.info("Search json {} for user exist", searchSourceBuilder.toString()); --> you can check the ES search json generated.
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = esclient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

**Above will give you the mail-id in search results and let me know if you face issues.**

Comment: Hi Opster, Thank you for reply back. could you tell me how to apply above setting and analyzer to existing index. I think without above setting and analyzer below piece of code won't work.

Comment: should i use existing index to apply setting or i need to create a new one.

Comment: Yes you have to apply these setting and without these it won't work. You can apply to existing or create a new index. Let me know if you face any issue and please comment whenever you are able to resolve it.

Comment: Could you tell me how to apply above settings. i am creating a setting object using XContentBuilder and applying it to PutMappingRequest like this 

client.indices().putMapping(putMappingRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

i have updated the question with setting object content.

Comment: Sure. I will check this and would get back to you.

Comment: @gyananayak do u need to create setting object using java code only, for testing purpose you can simply use the REST API to create a new setting and mappings for your index, as mentioned in my answer use `http://{{hostname}}:9200/` to create a new index with the given settings and mapping

Comment: above is working fine with newly created index. But for existing index it is not working. Could you tell me how it will work for existing index.

Comment: @gyananayak were u able to solve the issue with your setting object creation, I would suggest updating this question(remove settings part and ask it in another question) to make it more helpful for the community.

Comment: Hi @opster, i created a new index using reindex. Then close the index and applied the setting then open index. After that it worked. 
All this steps i performed on kibana.